# Where should I save a view file in laravel?

Tags: laravel

As I am new to laravel, I would like to know where to save a view file which I created as form.php and how to call it using routes.php

Comment: It is saved in **`resources/views`** and the views would have an extension **`blade.php`**

Comment: Start reading the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `/resources/views`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views

but you need to do some research on your own before asking that kind of questions on SO, or you will get a lot of down votes!

Here is a screenshot of properly installed Laravel 5.4

[image]

Comment: but I dont have file named resources in laravel project, I have 4 folders app, bootstrap, vendor, public and some php files

Comment: When you install laravel properly then you MUST have all those folders and files!

Comment: If you use Linux here is a good answer on how to install laravel on Ubuntu...it is a little bit old but it works! http://askubuntu.com/questions/764782/install-laravel-5-on-ubuntu-16-04/767970#767970

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will reinstall